# DataList ASP.NET catch event

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, datalist

i have a web user control (ascx1) which contains web user control (ascx2). Inside that ascx2 there is a dataList.

**ASCX1**:

```
Page_Load 
{ 
var bp = (Mbp)Page.LoadControl(<b>ASCX2</b>); 
bp.dataSource = new List<...> { ... }; 
placeholder.Controls.Add(bp); 
}
```

**ASCX2**

```
public List<TBusiness> dataSource; 
private static List<...> ds; 
private static ITemplate itemTemplate; 
private static ITemplate editTemplate; 

Page_Load
{ 
... 

    if (!this.IsPostBack) 
    { 
    ds = this.dataSource;   
    itemTemplate = new CustomTemplate(...);
    editTemplate = new CustomTemplate(...); 
    }

dataList.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate; 
dataList.EditItemTemplate = editTemplate; 
dataList.DataSource = ds; 
dataList.DataBind(); 
}
```

**ItemTemplate**

```
ImageButton {CommmandName="Edit"} 

protected void dataList_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
    { 
        dataList.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex; 
        dataList.DataBind(); 
    }
```

**EditTemplate:**

```
ImageButton {CommmandName="Delete"} 
ImageButton {CommmandName="Cancel"} 
ImageButton {CommmandName="Update"}
```

Problem  :
On click `ImageButton{CommmandName="Edit"}` change template to EditTemplate. Can editing elements, but ignoring ImageButton events on EditTemplate (Delete, Cancel, Update). On click these Imagebuttons do nothing, just change back to itemTemplate. Cannot catch event for these ImageButtons (Delete, Cancel, Update).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the ItemCommand event. I am not seeing evidence of this in your code.

Check the CommandName parameter to determine which action to take.

```
void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if ( e.CommandName = "Delete" ){
     // Perform Delete, etc.
     MyDL.EditItemIndex = -1;
     DataList.DataBind();
   }    
}
```